# show on mouse enter descendant / nested div in jquery

Tags: jquery, nested, mouseenter, descendant

Hi guys I'm very new to jQuery and in need of your help.

I'd like to make a grandchild/descendant div appear on mouse hover.
This code doesn't seem to work so I'd like to know what is wrong.

Here's the HTML markup:

```
<div id='#content'>

   <div class="main-div">   /* ------- parent ---- */

      <div class="col1"> (Wordpress content goes in here </div>
      <div class="col2"> (featured-photo here in second column) </div> /* ----- child ---- */
      <div class="col3"> 
        <div class="photo-controls"> .. </div>   /* ----- grandchild ---- */
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

I have this js code:

```
var $content = $('#content');

$content.on('mouseenter', '.main-div', function() {
        $(this).find('.photo-controls').show();
    }
});

$content.on('mouseleave', '.main-div', function() {
        $(this).find('.photo-controls').hide();
    }
});
```

Here's the css:

```
.photo-controls {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}
```

I've tried using children, siblings but they don't seem to pick up the descendant div to hover.

Comment: Remove the `#` from `<div id='#content'>`

Answer (score 0):

As Billyonecan stated in his comment, you don't need # symbols in the element id markup.

I've made some changes to your JS code and markup.

Revised markup:

```
<div id='content'>

  <div class="col1"> .. </div>
  <div class="col2"> .. </div> /* ----- child ---- */
  <div class="col3"> 
    <div class="photo-controls"> .. </div>   /* ----- grandchild ---- */
  </div>
```

Revised js:

```
$( "#content" ).mouseenter(function(){
          $('#content .photo-controls').toggle(true);
 }).mouseleave(function(){
          $('#content .photo-controls').toggle(false);
 });
```

Honestly, I'm not sure what

```
$masonryeman.on('mouseleave', '.thumb-holder', function() {
    $(this).find('.photo-controls').hide();
});
```

is supposed to do. as the var referenced wasn't shown in the code on declaration.

Comment: Prefixing variables with `$` is quite common. It allows you to easily distinguish between a jQuery object and a DOM object

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen it used before (Other than in PHP), Learn something new everyday :).  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the # from the HTML markup that was my mistake, but the problem is still there. I need to use $(this) because it's targeting the loop for each different posts in wordpress. The_content and featured_photo are within .main-div